# Universal hash functions - Proof

Tags: hash, hashing

#### Problem statement

Let $K$ be a set of keys with $|K| = n$ and define the index set $I = \{0, \ldots, m-1\}$. Now let $H = \{h \mid h : K \to I\}$, i.e. $H$ contains **all** hash functions which map the keys from $K$ to the set $\{0, \ldots, m-1\}$.

Prove or disprove that $H$ is universal.

#### Attempt

Reiterating the definition

> A family of hash functions $H$ is universal if and only if for $\forall x, y \in K, (x \neq y)$ we have
> $\left|\{h \in H : h(x) = h(y)\}\right| = \frac{|H|}{m}$

I know you can construct specific families of universal hash functions and there are families which aren't universal. But if you consider *all* of them how would you know which part would outweigh which to decide if this statement still holds?

I'm probably going the wrong way so I would appreciate any help or hints!

Answer (score 2):

Let us first look at the total number of hash functions in $H$. Since each key can be mapped to $m$ different indexes and there $n$ different keys. We get:

\begin{align}
|H| = m^{n}
\end{align}

Now, **without loss of generality**, let us consider the first two keys $x = k_{1}$ and $y = k_{2}$. We will compute the number of hash functions where $x$ and $y$ will collide i.e., $h(x) = h(y) = i$ for any $i \in \{0,\dotsc,m-1\}$.

\begin{align}
|\{h \in H : h(x) = h(y) = i\}| = m^{n-2}  
\end{align}

Therefore, summing up for all $i \in \{0,\dotsc,m-1\}$, we get:  $$|\{h \in H : h(x) = h(y)\}| = m^{n-1} = \frac{|H|}{m}$$

Hence, $H$ is a universal hash family.

Comment: Could you look at this? Thank you. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165770/finding-the-size-of-set-mathcalh